# PopupWindow how to change icon and background programmatically?

Tags: java, android

Have is xml file for PopupWindow:

[image]

How to programmatically replace the icon and Backgroud in this xml?

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: xml file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxhi0uFKK3upNWhJOV9oX2sxUEk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout menuLayout= (LinearLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(menuId, null);

int layoutCount = menuLayout.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < layoutCount; i++)  
{
    View itemView = menuLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if (itemView instanceof LinearLayout)
    {
        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView;
        int count = ((LinearLayout) itemView).getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            View view = itemLayout.getChildAt(j);
            if (view instanceof ImageView)
                ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
        }
    }
 }
```

You can find items using findViewById.

Answer (score 1):

XML layout for popup menu is normally created in a **menu** folder

You have to change it just before calling the popup.show()

```
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.name_of_xml_layout, popup.getMenu());
    popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.editmenubtn).setIcon(R.drawable.newicon);  //this line will change the icon of popup menu
    popup.show();
```

Comment: If adding items dynamically, you can also use: `popup.getMenu.add(0, id, Menu.NONE, "Menu Item 1").setIcon(R.drawable.newIcon);`

Answer (score 0):

```html
You can change the background by using 
  LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
ll.setBackground(...);
```

```html
ImageView i=popUpwindow.findViewById(R.id.image1);

i.setImageResource(id here);
or 
i.setImageDrawable(Drawable here);
```

Comment: ActivityMain.A.displayPopupWindow(ActivityAllApps.this, view, R.layout.popup_menu_all_apps_app);

Need programmatically to replace  green icons to other icons who will also be in the folder Drawable

Answer (score 0):

First initialize the imageView you want to change. Like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
```

then

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yournewIconId);
```

Similarly you can do it for the background change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a theme style as following:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    </style>
```

Following code works for me:

```
public void showPopUpMenu(final Context context, View view) {
            Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.PopupMenu);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view, Gravity.END);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_share:
                            shareWithFriends();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            try {
                Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                        Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                                .getClass().getName());
                        Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                                "setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                        setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            popup.show();
        }
```